# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Comparator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having a problem in mapping jpa, please if anyone has more experience in using jpa and could help me.

I have ran some searches in the internet, But nothings works for me.

I hope i ll get some fix!!

Thanks!

Here my Code:

Metodologia.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "metodologias")
public class Metodologia {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String nombre;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "METODOLOGIA_CONDICION",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "METODOLOGIA_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CONDICION_ID")}
        )

private List<Condicion> condiciones;

public Metodologia(String n) {
    this.nombre = n;
    this.condiciones = new ArrayList<Condicion>();
}

public void addCondicion(Condicion con) {
    this.condiciones.add(con);
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public ArrayList<ResultadoEmpresa> evaluarEmpresas(ArrayList<Empresa> empresas, ArrayList<Indicador> indicadores) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<ResultadoEmpresa> resultados = new ArrayList<ResultadoEmpresa>();
    ArrayList<ResultadoEmpresa> res;

    empresas.forEach(emp->resultados.add(new ResultadoEmpresa(emp.getNombre(), 0)));

    for (Condicion con : condiciones) {
        res = con.evaluar(empresas, indicadores);
        for (ResultadoEmpresa resemp : res) 
            for (ResultadoEmpresa emp : resultados)
                if (emp.getEmpresa().equals(resemp.getEmpresa()))
                    emp.sumar(resemp.getValor());
    }

    return ordenarLista(resultados);
}

Comparator<ResultadoEmpresa> byValor = new Comparator<ResultadoEmpresa>() {
    public int compare(ResultadoEmpresa left, ResultadoEmpresa right) {
        if (left.getValor() > (right.getValor())) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
};

private ArrayList<ResultadoEmpresa> ordenarLista(ArrayList<ResultadoEmpresa> emp) {
    Collections.sort(emp, byValor);

    return emp;
}
}
```

This is a error report at the execute,

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Comparator, at table: metodologias, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(byValor)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Comparator, at table: metodologias, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(byValor)]*

This means: JPA /Hibernate want to interpret field `Comparator byValor` as persistent column (prepare to store in database)

JPA has two, (theoretically) exclusive method to set annotations: on field, or on getter.
I assume, first annotation for **field** It switch the whole business to 'field'. 
Then all fields JPA provider interpret as data persistable to DB, Comparator too, which has no sense.

How to correct:
mark field as 'transient', to be not persisted.

```
@Transient
Comparator<ResultadoEmpresa> byValor = new Comparator<ResultadoEmpresa>()       {
...
{
```

Disclaimer: 
*Not tested in reality, interpretation only based on JPA theory.* 
Maybe You have next errors.

EDIT: alternative solution: remove such functions out of entity class. I can accept entity class implementing Comparable, but not too much 'functors' (personal opinion). 
Good designed 'entity class' is similar to 'POJO' concept, so removing such function looks OK.

Comparators are usually provided near sort() call, for example on sorting by name, second by age etc...  not in data class.

Generally, @Transient is good annotation for every field, You want to stop persisting